# How should I troubleshootiing 'strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "to": invalid syntax' in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, endpoint, target, parsefloat

As the titles. I scraped the metrics of pods,encountered the errors in the prometheus target as follow:

**target:** http://192.168.62.150:20200/metrics

**error:** strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "to": invalid syntax

How prometheus parse the metrics and where should I find the data with error.

@DazWilkin
The part of curl http://192.168.62.136:20200/metrics  as follow:20200 is the port of consult envoy，9090 is the port the productapi service exposed.

```
envoy_server_initialization_time_ms_bucket{local_cluster="product-api",consul_source_service="product-api",consul_source_namespace="default",consul_source_partition="default",consul_source_datacenter="dc1",le="300000"} 1
envoy_server_initialization_time_ms_bucket{local_cluster="product-api",consul_source_service="product-api",consul_source_namespace="default",consul_source_partition="default",consul_source_datacenter="dc1",le="600000"} 1
envoy_server_initialization_time_ms_bucket{local_cluster="product-api",consul_source_service="product-api",consul_source_namespace="default",consul_source_partition="default",consul_source_datacenter="dc1",le="1800000"} 1
envoy_server_initialization_time_ms_bucket{local_cluster="product-api",consul_source_service="product-api",consul_source_namespace="default",consul_source_partition="default",consul_source_datacenter="dc1",le="3600000"} 1
envoy_server_initialization_time_ms_bucket{local_cluster="product-api",consul_source_service="product-api",consul_source_namespace="default",consul_source_partition="default",consul_source_datacenter="dc1",le="+Inf"} 1
envoy_server_initialization_time_ms_sum{local_cluster="product-api",consul_source_service="product-api",consul_source_namespace="default",consul_source_partition="default",consul_source_datacenter="dc1"} 1350
envoy_server_initialization_time_ms_count{local_cluster="product-api",consul_source_service="product-api",consul_source_namespace="default",consul_source_partition="default",consul_source_datacenter="dc1"} 1
failed to scrape metrics at url "http://127.0.0.1:9090/metrics"
```

Comment: A good next step would be to browse the Endpoint (`http://192.168.62.136:20200/metrics`) directly (using a browser or `curl`). Prometheus was able to access this private network address directly but you may need to connect to that network from your host. The result should be a page of text representing Prometheus' exposition format describing the metrics and their values. Prometheus expects every metric to parse to a float64. Somewhere in the list of metrics, there's an erroneous value (that's not converting to a float64) and may be (unsure) the value `to`. This is the issue.

Comment: Prometheus is unable to parse the metrics that it's scraping (browsing) because, at least one of them, appears to have the value `to` when it should have a numeric value.

Comment: @DazWilkin
where should I look for the erroneous valus "to". And the result of "curl http://192.168.62.136:20200/metrics" have appended to the issue.

Comment: I encourage to read Prometheus' documentation to familiarize yourself with its workings. See [notation](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/) for an example of how metrics are exported. Please copy and paste text rather than use screenshots. The image content is unclear but includes "failed to scrape ..." which is problematic.

Comment: @DazWilkin
I've posted in the issue。

Comment: Thanks for pasting the text. To reiterate, the metrics text should **not** include the last line `failed to scrape ...`. You should determine why that's present.